# Firefox, saving all images from every page so that they are retrievable?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I'm having a bit of trouble finding a way to do this, I know that firefox saves images to a cache file but it is in a gzip archive file that I am unable to unzip (just gives error when I try, I'm using Ubuntu, so yes i do have gzip support).. I have looked for plugsin to do this but haven't found anything of use.. I want it so that, for every page I visit that all images on the page are automatically saved so as to be usable in the future.. if there is a way to get the images from the cache I would appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction.. thanks for any info

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question, and Firefox Quantum has happened since it was written.  Just to update, there is an add-on that works with Quantum (also available for Chromium-based browsers), called [Download All Images](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-all-images-webextension/?src=search) by belav (developer's page [here](https://add0n.com/save-images.html)), which offers a lot of flexibility in selecting all images or ones meeting various criteria.  I've used it a few times.  The selection criteria comes in handy on something like an Amazon product page, which has a lot of images you may not want.

Edit: At the time I wrote this answer, this add-on was titled "Download Them All", which could have been confused with the Nils Maier add-on recommended in 2010 by Andrew Richard Gray and Licargon.  I just updated the add-on name here to its current title.

Note that the Nils Maier "DownloadThemAll" add-on does now appear to have been rewritten as a WebExtension, and currently looks to be Quantum-compatible.  I haven't tested that one.

Comment: The guy that wrote this question hasn't been active on superuser since 2012. :)

Comment: @raphael75, you're right, of course, but answers aren't just for the original poster.  The purpose of the site is to be a knowledge base of solutions that can be shared by other people with the same problem.  This answer was for readers landing on the page now.  :-)

Comment: That's very true and thank you for posting your answer all these years later! I just wanted to let you know that he probably will never mark an answer as answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [CacheViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2489/) add-on and see if it's something like what you're looking for.

I'm not sure if it will let you automatically save the photos, but you can at least access them. And it's an add-on as opposed to a stand alone program which is a plus.

Or you could try the [Mihov Batch Picture Downloader](http://www.picturedownloader.net/features.php). You give it a site and it will crawl the site for image files and download them.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the Firefox "Save Web Page (complete)" feature of Firefox not work for you?

If you simply want to automate the page saving, create a simple macro with [SAVEAS](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) in iMacros for Firefox (or use the [take browser screenshot of the complete website](http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Web_Site_Screenshot) feature of iMacros).

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite fond of the https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/201/ (Downthemall) application. You can specify extensions, and it'll locate and download any links ending in that extension. In your case: Image files :)

Comment: DownThemAll and FlashGet have been mythical prior to the great quantum depression of 57. Apparently [DTA doesn't worth it anymore](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/reviews/?score=3) and FG never recovered.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat utility called DownloadThemAll which allows you to download Images / Videos etc (basically anything that you can download by right-clicking -> Save Link

I used this Add-On in Windows and was delighted to find it available for FireFox in Ubunto 10.04.

I hope this helps,

regards ...