# What about Firefox addon can get all image url in current visit webpage?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox, saving all images from every page so that they are retrievable?](https://superuser.com/questions/180827/firefox-saving-all-images-from-every-page-so-that-they-are-retrievable)

What about Firefox addon can get all image url in current visit webpage?

Answer (score 1):

[DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) is your best bet, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I fall you want are the URLs, then just right-click the page, select `View Page Info` and click the Media tab. Anything in here with "Image" as the type is a picture, and you can easily see the URL, no add-ons required.

If you actually want to download all the picture, then as clpo13 says, [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) is a very good download manager that will happily download all the images on a page (or follow the URLs to grab all the full sized images linked from a page).